# Unable to install a PyPi package in Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-composer

I tried installing `boto3` on Composer but after some time I received the following error:

[image]

Any ideas what's going on?
I typed `boto3` in the package name without specifying the version.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I have tried installing `boto3` in Google Cloud Composer and it worked for me. It says under the `PYPI PACKAGES` that I have `boto3>=1.9.86`. So try specifying the version in the requirements file.

In `Cloud Shell` create a `requirements.txt` and add `boto3>=1.9.86`. This will install **boto3** version **1.9.86** or newer, if there is available. During the procedure of creating the Google Cloud Composer Environment, you specified the Python version. Make sure that boto3 is compatible with that version.

Run the following command:

```
gcloud composer environments update ENVIRONMENT-NAME \
--update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt \
--location LOCATION
```

And wait. It will take some time, but boto3 should install successfully.

More information can be found in [Installing Python Dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-package) documentation.

Comment: good catch @Andrei Cusnir